# User input not writing to Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried different solutions all day and I can't get my form to write it's user input content to Firebase. The rules are currently open to everyone so I know that's not the problem. It's a three step signup process on three separate pages, however, the first step (or user input on page one) won't write to the database while the others work fine and I have setup the same way.

At this point, I'm completely lost since I've tried everything.

Here's my JS:

```
var mvrName = document.getElementById("name");
var mvrAddress = document.getElementById("address");
var mvrZip = document.getElementById("zip");
var mvrPhone = document.getElementById("phone");
var mvrEmail = document.getElementById("email");
var _mvrName, _mvrAddress, _mvrZip, _mvrPhone, _mvrEmail;
var date = Date();

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('nextBtn').onclick = function() {
    _mvrName = mvrName.value;
    _mvrAddress = mvrAddress.value;
    _mvrZip = mvrZip.value;
    _mvrEmail = mvrPhone.value;
    _mvrPhone = mvrEmail.value;

    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    firebaseRef.child("Contact Info").push({
        Name: _mvrName,
        Address: _mvrAddress,
        Zip: _mvrZip,
        Email: _mvrEmail,
        Phone: _mvrPhone,
        Date_Created: date
    });
    secondStep();
  };
};

function secondStep() {
  window.location.href = 'companyInfo.html';
}
```

If I remove the 'secondStep()' method call then data is written to Firebase, but If I don't then it goes to the next page on button click but data isn't written to Firebase.

Here's my HTML:

```
<head>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
          ...
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

  <!-- Loading Goodle Places Library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&libraries=places"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav>...</nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4>Contact Details</h4>
        <input class="inputs" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input class="inputs" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Street Address" />
        <input class="inputs" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Zip" />
        <input class="inputs" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input class="inputs" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
      <button id="nextBtn"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="contactInfo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Like I said, I've been trying to get this portion of user input to write to the Firebase all day with no luck on button click unless I remove the function to go to the next page, but that's my ultimate goal is to write and then take them to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the write to the database to complete before you transition to the next page.

One common way to do this, is to use the `Promise` that `push()` returns. Once the write complete, the `then()` method of the promise is called and you can safely change the window location:

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
firebaseRef.child("Contact Info").push({
    Name: _mvrName,
    Address: _mvrAddress,
    Zip: _mvrZip,
    Email: _mvrEmail,
    Phone: _mvrPhone,
    Date_Created: date
}).then(function() {
    secondStep();
});
```

The rest of your code can remain unchanged.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Frank